# Проброс подключения к БД в функцию php

Tags: php, mysql

У меня имеется страница на php, к ней подключается еще две.

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'function.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'connectdb.php');
```

в `connect.db` подключение к базе вида

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin', 'password', 'base');
```

В функции внутри надо снова прописывать подключение к БД, можно ли как то пробросить эту переменную подключения к БД в функции, и как ее правильно вызвать изнутри?

```
function my_function($c)
{

}
```

Comment: либо аргументом функции, либо через global.
процедурное снова в моде?

Comment: это похапе. а это значит, что в моде видеокурсы, которые преподают новейшие достижения РНР из 1998 года.

Comment: Я бы в класс засунул. И потом использовал бы так:  `$DB::conntection();`

Comment: @Ипатьев кинь ссылкой на хорошую статью по программированию на `php`. Не документацию.

Comment: @doox911 http://phptherightway.ru/

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо. Это видал. Это из личного архива?) Есть ли там ещё интересное? Больше флудить не буду.

Comment: @doox911 это то, что рекомендуют на англоязычных ресурсах. просто за неимением лучшего. Там, конечно, галопом по европам, но хотя бы откровенной ерунды не советуют.

Answer (score 1):

Простой классс подключения к БД:

```
class Db{

    public static function getConnection(){
        $paramsPath = ROOT . '/config/db_params.php';
        $params = include($paramsPath);
        $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']};charset=UTF8";
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);
        return $db;
    }
}
```

Применение дальше по коду:

```
$db = DB::getConnection();
```

Comment: ну так эта "статика"тоже будет создавать новое подключение каждый раз. и тоже убьет сервер

Comment: @Ипатьев подскажите что не убъёт?  Применить паттерн `singlton`?

Comment: @doox911 Статика не статика, это зависит от шаблона проектирования. Но в любом случае серверу смерть!

Comment: @VadimPedchenko почему?

Comment: Правильно реализованный синглтон будет создавать только одно соединение с БД. В этом и состоит его предназначение. однако архитектурно синглтон не сильно лучше пресловутого global, и по возможности лучше его избегать. но для уровня автора вопроса это будет, возможно, наименьшим из зол

Comment: @Ипатьев так какая лучшая практика реализации подключения к бд? Я что-то уже путаться начинаю(

Comment: Это наверное, странно, но я написал в своем ответе. Ни в одном профессиональном приложении, написанном по современным стандартам, синглтон не используется.

Comment: @Ипатьев ок. А как правильно делать? Если мой вариант убьёт сервер.

Comment: Ну это зависит от архитектуры приложения. Если это по большей части процедурный код, без тестов, с подключением к единственной БД, без планов по развитию во что-то большее - используйте синглтон. Вот пример [удобного синглтона для PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#singleton), с примерами использования. Если же хотите в принципе научиться современным принципам программирования, то учите фреймворк, Laravel или Symfony. Там такими вопросами, как подключение к БД, заниматься не придется, они все сделают за вас.

Comment: @Ипатьев а Yii? С фреймворками всё и так понятно, что там многими исправлено и используется оптимальная практика. И исходя из вашего ответа, для лучшая реализация в них. Ок. Погляжу код.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и самый правильный вариант - передавать в качестве параметра.

```
function my_function($mysqli, $c)
{

}
```

Это добавит немного писанины сейчас, но сэкономит много потраченного впустую времени в будущем.

Answer (score 0):

1). Используйте [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)!

2). Создайте класс обёртку PDO, либо используйте существующую, коих на [GitHub](https://github.com) полно.

3). Читайте [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/)!

Просто пример:

```
class Database {

    private $connection;

    public function __construct() {
       $this->connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin', 'password', 'base');  
    }

    public function dropTable($table) {
        $this->connection->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table');
    }

    ////////
}
```

Использование в другом классе:

```
class Another {

    private $database;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->database = new Database();
    }

    public function someAction() {
        $this->database->dropTable('test');
    }

}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88738/discussion-on-answer-by-vadim-pedchenko-------php).

Comment: Приведенный пример нельзя использовать, он создает больше проблем, чем решает. Если автор вопроса применит его, то новое соединение с БД будет создаваться при каждом вызове функции. Это, скорее, основы РНР, но не лишне будет их повторить: Подключение к одной и той же БД должно быть всегда одно на протяжении всего выполнения скрипта, иначе будут проблемы, например: Соединение с БД - относительно затратная операция, приложение будет работать дольше; возникнут сложности с транзакциями; множество подключений приведет к быстрому исчерпанию ресурсов сервера БД и ошибке Too many connections.